# Does `dash` support `bash` style arrays?

Tags: linux, dash-shell

In the `dash` shell environment I am looking to split a string into arrays. The following code works in `bash` but not in `dash`.

```
IFS=""
var="this is a test|second test|the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
IFS="|"
test=( $var )
echo ${test[0]}
echo ${test[1]}
echo ${test[2]}
```

My Question

Does `dash` support arrays in this style. If not are there any suggestions for parsing this out into an another type of variable **without** the use of a loop?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`dash` does not support arrays. You could try something like this:

```
var="this is a test|second test|the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS="|"
set -- $var
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"      # Note: if more than $9 you need curly braces e.g. "${10}"
IFS=$oldIFS
```

---

Note: Since the variable expansion `$var` is unquoted it gets split into fields according to `IFS`, which was set to a vertical bar. These fields become the parameters of the `set` command and as a result `$1` `$2` etc contain the sought after values.

`--` (end of options) is used so that no result of the variable expansion can be interpreted as an option to the set command.

Comment: You may want to use `set -f` to disable globbing. See note from shellcheck here: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086#exceptions