# Shell script read multiple inputs from user

Tags: bash, shell

How to read any number of inputs from user at once and store it into an array.
For example this will read only a single input at a time

```
  read -p "Please enter username: " username
  echo "Dear $username,"
```

I want something like:

```
read -p "Please enter location names separated by space: "
```

How would i store location names into an array and then loop through it.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Please enter location names separated by space: " -a arr
for location in "${arr[@]}"; do 
   echo "$location"
done
```

Comment: script.sh: 2: read: Illegal option -a
script.sh: 3: script.sh: Bad substitution

Comment: @JohnWick,  the code is good(ish) Bash code.  `read` in Bash has had the `-a` option for a very long time, so I suspect that you are running the code with another shell, possibly Dash.  If you run  the code with `bash script.sh`, or make the program executable and run it with `./script.sh`, it should work unless you are using a decades-old version of Bash.  You can't do what you want with Dash because it doesn't support arrays.  See [Does `dash` support `bash` style arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14594033/4154375).

Answer (score 1):

```
read -p "Please enter location names separated by space: " location_names

for location in $location_names
do
echo $location
done
```

Testing.

> Please enter location names separated by space: paris london new-york
>   paris
>   london
>   new-york

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how _location_names_ becomed an array ?

Comment: `for` parses `location_names` with the space separator, technically location_names did not become an array